# MS SQL Server 2012 Data Quality Services (DQS) installation failure

Tags: sql-server-2012, data-quality-services

I tried to install MS SQL Server 2012 DQS using DQSInstaller.exe, but installation failed. In the console output started by the install tool (DQSInstaller.exe) I found this line:

```
Password validation failed. 
The password does not meet Windows policy requirements because it is too short.
```

It was a bit odd, since my password was 15 characters long, but who knows. I used a different one and made it sure that it is 30 chars long. That didn't help and the installer insisted that the password is still too short.

Next thing was upgrading my SQL Server 2012 to SP1. That didn't help either.

The Installer is started with admin privileges. The database instance is NOT a default instance, but I see the script finds that out by itself.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was starting one of the installer scripts manually and starting installer again afterwards.

I've searched for recreate_schema.bat script on my PC, opened cmd, changed directory to the script location and started the script the way installer starts it...

> cd C:\Users{my user name}\AppData\Local\Temp\j1bnpjct.k3b
>
> recreate_schema.bat RS-1OT-45OAR200\MSSQL2012 DQS SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

It finished without errors.

After that I started installer again and it worked.

I hope this will help someone.